# Connecting Twitter API to a Big Data Environment?

Tags: bigdata, visualization, apache-hadoop, tableau

I am trying to get live twitter data and store it in a Hadoop environment. Currently, I am learning how to push the data into a Cloudera environment and process it.

My questions are:

1. Is Cloudera the best environment? If not what is the alternative?
2. My next step is to connect tableau to the hadoop environment and visualize it.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: why do not use spark ? https://www.tableau.com/stories/workbook/provide-transparencies-progress-and-impact-programs

Answer (score 0):

There are three main contenders **Cloudera, MapR**, and **Hortonworks**. But among all these 3 Cloudera and MapR are better solutions if money is not an issue and you'd like to get some advanced features.

Cloudera has **Impala** which may be a killer feature for some. MapR has some unique HA attributes and uses a **NFS compatible filesystem**. MapR is supposedly the fastest Hadoop solution in the market. You can find more information on this on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-best-distribution-of-Hadoop-Is-Cloudera-the-clear-leader-in-this-space)

Now for your 2nd question, go through these articles.

- [Tableau on Top of Hadoop](http://blog.predie.com/2016/02/21/tableau-on-top-of-hadoop/)
- [Connecting to Hadoop Hive](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/hadoop-hive-connection)
- [Administering Hadoop and Hive for Tableau Connectivity](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/administering-hadoop-hive)

Hope it helps!